# ngrx: selector type mapping

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

This is my `IStore`:

```
export interface IStore {
  plans: IPlanRedux;
}
```

where `IPlanRedux` is:

```
export interface IPlanRedux {
    entities: { [key: string]: IPlan };
    ids: Array<string>;
}

export interface IPlan {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
}
```

So, I need to create selectors from my `plan` state. The selectors I've created are:

`plan.selectors.ts`:

```
export const getEntities = (planRdx: IPlanRedux) => planRdx.entities;
export const getIds = (planRdx: IPlanRedux) => planRdx.ids;

export const getAll = createSelector(getEntities, getIds, (entities, ids) => { return ids.map(id => entities[id]); });
```

and on `root.selectors.ts`:

```
export const getPlansState = (state: IStore) => state.plans;
export const getPlanEntities = createSelector(getPlansState, fromPlans.getAll);
```

I've stuck with a compiler error I don't know how to solve. I'm trying to create an subscription using `getPlanEntities` selector into my component in order to get all entities:

```
this.store$.select(fromRoot.getPlanEntities)
    .map(plan => {
        if (plan.id != null)
        {
            return {id: plan.id, text: plan.name};
        }
    });
```

The problem is with the parameter type `plan`. Compiler tells me that `plan`'s type is `IPlan[]`, instead of a single `IPlan`. So, I'm getting compiler errors like `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IPlan[]'` since `plan` is an `IPlan[]` instead of an `IPlan`.

I don't know how to deal with this issue. Is there anyway to get single entities one by one instead of a single array?

**EDIT**

The goal I want to achieve is to make an `Observable<IPlan>` into my component from `this.store$.select(fromRoot.getPlanEntities)`:

```
private plans$: Observable<IPlan>;
constructor(private store$: Store<IStore>, private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, injector: Injector)
{
    this.plans$ = this.store$.select(fromRoot.getPlanEntities)
        .map(planEntities => {
            return planEntities
                .find(plan => plan.id != null)
                .map(plan => ({id :plan.id, text: plan.name}));
        });
 ...
```

And use it on template in order to list all current plans:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div *ngIf="plans$ | async">
        <div [innerHTML]="(plans$ | async).name"></div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the `map` here :

```
this.store$.select(fromRoot.getPlanEntities)
  .map(plan => {
      if (plan.id != null)
      {
          return {id: plan.id, text: plan.name};
      }
  });
```

It's not an ES6 `map` but a `map` on an `Observable`.
You're simply retrieving your `planEntities`
If you want to get one entity, you should do something like that :

```
this.store$.select(fromRoot.getPlanEntities)
  .map(planEntities => {
    return planEntities
      .find(plan => plan.id !== null)
      .map(plan => ({ id: plan.id, text: plan.name }));
  })
  .do((plan: {id: any, text: string}) => /* DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE */);
```

Comment: I'm getting this compiler message: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'IPlan'` -> `find(...).map()`.

Comment: I've just edited the post in order to give a bit more information about what I'm trying to get...